# paypal subcription: Can I make the first payment different ammount?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on Paypal Payment Pro and need to have a special recursive payment.

In this case. My client want to make the first month payment is 0, and in following months, the payment will be 5$ each.

Is there any way or document about this? I personally don't know what it's called so I can't google around.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *side-note: I guess you mean "recurrent", not "recursive"*

Comment: or perhaps recurring?  And from my perspective, a payment of $0 does not count as a payment.  Are you perhaps saying you want recurring payments of $5, starting next month?

Comment: something like charing an initial amount of 5$ and from the next month, it will be 7$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can do that,please use below fields as hidden and try.

```
<input type="hidden" name="a1"value="0.00">  
<input type="hidden"name="p1" value="15"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">
```

here is the code by which you can payment for first 15 days free. you can set any amount in field a1,p1,t1 to make payment..

here a1 is the amount you want to pay, p1 is frequency of payment, and t1 is time period you want to recurring..where D=daily,M=monthly,Y=yearly.

Try this.it may be helpful to you..

Comment: This works great. You just need to make sure to detect new variables on your callback script that their API called.

Answer (score 0):

Should this question be closed due to your other question?  I'd look into the TRIALBILLINGPERIOD and TRIALAMT parameters in the [PayPal Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments).

Answer (score 0):

Just start the users subscription ONE month from today, since it's O dollars anyways.  I charge my clients $1, as there are fees, and just set their payments to start one month from today.  Charging them something let's you know that they can pay it, and gives you a month to hack out the details if their card is borked.